# Distributed DDD entities with Akka

Tags: scala, akka

Suppose we'd have a large number of persistent Person actors, each constructed with an identity and a name argument. What would be the best way to distribute these actors in a cluster, in such a manner that:

- new actors are appointed a node by strategy X (round robin, consistent hash, etc.)
- a "coordinator" actor contains a mapping from identity to ActorRef
- one or more nodes can fail and the affected actors are recovered on other nodes
- there is no SPF

I've considered the following, which doesn't seem to solve the problem:

- Cluster sharding; all actors are initialised equally and created by coordinator
- Cluster aware routing; groups or pools are fixed size and can't be modified dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you pretty much exactly are describing Akka cluster sharding and there isn't enough information to see why it would not fit.

The common solution to deal with such a design problem is to have an uninitialized state of the sharded entity where it only accepts an initialize command containing the needed values (so something like `CreateUser(id, name)`) and when it gets that it toggles to its "normal" behavior.

Another option could be to introduce an intermediate actor that doesn't start the actual actor until it has extracted the name value if you have no means to change the design of your Person actor.

Ofc. you could also drop down to the Akka cluster APIs directly and build something that exactly matches your use case, but handling redistribution on cluster topology change (add, remove nodes etc) is far from trivial to get right.

I think you would also come to the realisation that achieving such a tool that is entirely non-invasive for your entities without the sharding solution being tightly coupled with you business logic is very hard.